# Python Blackjack lists and special values

Tags: python, list, function, blackjack, playing-cards

I am trying to debug a game of Blackjack in python, but I cannot figure out how to implement Ace through King once the hand is dealt. I need a hint or something... Am I overlooking something obvious maybe?

```
MAX = 21


# main function

def main():
    # Local variables

    hand1 = 0

    hand2 = 0

    deck = create_deck()

    while hand1 <= 21 and hand2 <= 21:
        card1, value1 = deck.popitem()

        hand1 = update_hand_value(hand1, value1, card1)

        card2, value2 = deck.popitem()

        hand2 = update_hand_value(hand2, value2, card2)

        print('Player 1 was dealt', card1)

        print('Player 2 was dealt', card2)

        print()

    # Determine the winner.

    if hand1 > MAX and hand2 > MAX:

        print("There is no winner.")

    elif hand1 > 21:

        print("Player 2 wins.")

    else:

        print("Player 1 wins.")


def create_deck():
    # Set up local variables

    suits = ['Spades', 'Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']

    # unused currently, needs to be implemented
    special_values = {'Ace': 1, 'King': 10, 'Queen': 10, 'Jack': 10}

    numbers = ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack']

    for i in range(2, 11):
        numbers.append(str(i))

    # Initialize deck

    deck = {}

    for suit in suits:

        for num in numbers:

            # Values 2-10.

            if num.isnumeric():
                deck[num + ' of ' + suit] = int(num)
            else:
                deck[num + ' of ' + suit] = str(num)
            # values 1 and 11

    return deck


def update_hand_value(hand, value, card):
    if not card == 'Ace':

        return hand, value

    # Adding 11 would cause to go over the maximum.

    elif hand > 10:

        # Value is 1 by default.

        return hand, value

    else:

        return hand + 11


# Call the main function.

main()


# Call the main function.

main()
```

Cards will be dealt until a player wins.

Sample output:

Player 1 was dealt 2 of Diamonds
Player 2 was dealt 8 of Spades

Player 1 was dealt 6 of Diamonds
Player 2 was dealt 5 of Diamonds

Player 1 was dealt 4 of Clubs
Player 2 was dealt 8 of Diamonds

Player 1 was dealt 7 of Clubs
Player 2 was dealt 3 of Spades

Player 1 wins.

EDIT:
I have modified my program, but I am getting a new error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sean/PycharmProjects/SeanPython/ISY150/Demo/Blackjack.py", line 99, in 
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Sean/PycharmProjects/SeanPython/ISY150/Demo/Blackjack.py", line 17, in main
    while hand1 <= 21 and hand2 <= 21:
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() <= int()

I do not understand, at line 17 I'm not comparing a tuple with an int as far as I know...

Comment: Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698740/treating-a-string-as-an-integer/30698781#30698781

Comment: Had to edit my program. Also, I imagine this program has to be done a set way. I actually have another working blackjack program. This one just needs to be done this way. I have to debug it as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have different return types with your `update_hand_value` function. You are returning a tuple within your `if` and `elif` statements, but an integer within the `else`.

There are a bunch of other problems though, so I'll walk through a few suggestions to help you.

1) You are using `.pop()` from a `dict` which was created in order. Therefore, you will always get the same ordering of cards. Try shuffling the deck using `np.random.shuffle` before you create the dict from those lists. Specifically do `np.random.shuffle(suits)` and `np.random.shuffle(numbers)` right before you do your `for` loop in `create_deck()`

2) Use this:
`if type(num) == int:
                deck[str(num) + ' of ' + suit] = int(num)
            else:
                deck[num + ' of ' + suit] = str(num) #here ace, queen, and king, have strings as value in key:value pairs`

3) you never actually update the hand value in `update_hand_value()` so try this:

```
    if card != 'Ace': #complete all cases where card was not an ace 
      if type(value) == int: #a number was drawn - add number to hand
        hand = hand + value
        return hand
      elif type(value) == str: #this is a jack, queen, or king - add ten to hand
        hand = hand + 10
        return hand

    else: #card was an ace
        if hand + 11 == 21: #stop
            hand = hand + 11
            return hand
        elif hand + 11  > 21: #only add one
            hand = hand + 1
            return hand
```

4) finally, you need to keep track of the total cards a player has. An 11 for ace can switch to a one if a card brings over 21. I'll leave this to you to figure out, but try passing a list to update hand and search through it for aces.

Cheers